# Create dynamically named variables based on array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array and I want to create new variables based on the keys.

I have written this code, but it returns `NULL`:

```
$a = array("test" => array("a", "b", "c"));
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($value as $v){
            $i++;
            $$key[$i] = $v;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($test);
?>
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make that:

```
${$key}[$i] = $v;
```

- `$$key[$i]` means "the variable whose name is `$key[$i]`".
- `${$key}[$i]` means "position `$i` from the variable whose name is `$key`".

Also, it would be nice if you could initialize that `$test` array, so you won't get notices. Add the following before the second `foreach`:

```
$$key = array();
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 to @Radu's answer, but you should also think about if these solutions would work for you:

```
$a = array("test" => array("a", "b", "c"));
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
      $$key = array_values($value);
    }
}
var_dump($test);
```

Or:

```
$a = array("test" => array("a", "b", "c"));
extract($a);
var_dump($test);
```

See: [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$$key[$i]` tries to get the variable whose name matches the value of `$key[$i]`. You could get a reference to $$key first, and then add an item to that reference:

```
$a = array("test" => array("a", "b", "c"));
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($value as $v){
            $i++;
            $x = & $$key;
            $x[$i] = $v;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($test);
?>
```

[edit]

But I see, I'm somewhat slow in testing and writing an answer, since another good answer has been posted minutes ago. Still keeping this, since it uses a different and not much more complex approach.